# Count of all dates in an array which are present between two other columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My JSON looks like this

```json
{"array":["2021-01-17","2021-01-25"], "beginDate": "2021-01-01", "endDate": "2021-01-20"}
```

I want to find the count of all dates in the `array` which are present between `beginDate` and `endDate`.

I was trying to create a sequence of dates between begin and end date and doing an `array_intersect`. Similar to this:

```sql
select size(array_intersect(array("2021-12-02","2021-12-05","2021-12-10"),(sequence(to_date("2021-12-01"), date_add(to_date("2021-12-06"),-1), interval 1 day))))
```

But I am getting:

> array_intersect should have been two arrays with same element type, but it's [array<string>, array<date>]

When I run it on my JSON.

So I believe I need to convert my array to `array<date>`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that both arrays are `array<date>`. In your example, the first array was `array<string>`, which caused an error when you intersect it with an `array<date>`.

```
select 
    size(
        array_intersect(
            transform(array("2021-12-02","2021-12-05","2021-12-10"), x -> date(x)),
            sequence(to_date("2021-12-01"), date_add(to_date("2021-12-06"), -1), interval 1 day)
        )
    )
;
```

This query gives `2`.

---

For your initial question, you can try this query:

```
select 
    size(
        array_intersect(
            transform(array, x -> date(x)),
            sequence(to_date(begin), date_add(to_date(end), -1), interval 1 day)
        )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can count the elements in a much simpler way. Using only [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#aggregate) function, you'll iterate through the elements of the `array` column and count only those which are between `beginDate` and `endDate` :

```sql
SELECT aggregate(
           array, 
           0, 
           (acc, x) -> acc + IF(x BETWEEN beginDate AND endDate, 1, 0)
       ) AS count
```

For the example you gave:

```
+------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|array                               |beginDate |endDate   |
+------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|[2021-12-02, 2021-12-05, 2021-12-10]|2021-12-01|2021-12-06|
+------------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

It returns :

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    2|
+-----+
```